# How to use @ApiImplicitParams in Swagger for .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I have added an api that requires a dropdown menu for post method parameters. I found the Java way as below:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "test")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "type", value = "category", dataType = "String", paramType = "query",
                allowableValues = "apple,leechee,pineapple", allowMultiple = true)
})
@RequestMapping(value = "/select", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public String[] mystyle(String[] type) {
    return type;
}
```

But I cannot add this parameter in C#, could anyone help me to specify how to do so? Thanks.